# MySQL VB.Net Connection Problems

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have setup a MySQL database locally and using the MySQL Workbench, i have setup accounts on which i can access later but when i tried to connect using VB.Net, i have receive an error "Access denied for user root@localhost (using password: YES)". I have tried to grant all the privileges to root but still getting the same error. I am using MySQL Connector 5.*

```
 string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=reportdata;password=root!@#";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
```

but when i tried this:

```
 string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=mysql;password=";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
```

It connected successfully.

Hoping that someone can help me on this, its dragging me like 4 hours now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please log onto the MySQL console and change the password to what you desire:

```
MySQL 5.7.5 and Before 

SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('root!@#');

5.7.6 and Later

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root!@#';
```

Answer (score 0):

Root user of mysql doesn't have password by default.

Check this please for more details https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html